# Display content of website A to website B without redirection

Tags: php, mysql, apache, redirect, iframe

I am working on a webapp where users can create a profile and add their custom domain. 
Eg. If user profile is https://webapp.com/profile/, he/she can see that same profile on https://userdomain.com/ by adding A record.

I have figured out how to display particular profile to user but the problem is I dont want to use an iFrame and just realized that iframe are blocked my major adblockers.

This is similar to the feature of about.me premium domain mapping. Any ideas or suggestions to do this?

I'm using

1) PHP

2) Apache

3) MySQL

4) Ubuntu

Comment: Do a GET request to website A to get the content and display it on the website B

Comment: Content as in, I want to display the whole page of website A to the custom domain along with css and images